# OData defaults to pascal case when using $select or $filter

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .net core 3.1 web api project, I am using `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Odata` and `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`. My startup looks like this:

```
    services.AddOData();
            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                IEnumerable<ODataOutputFormatter> outputFormatters =
                    options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>()
                        .Where(foramtter => foramtter.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0);

                foreach (var outputFormatter in outputFormatters)
                {
                    outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/odata"));
                }

            }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseCamelCasing(false);
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() };
            });
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
                endpoints.Select().OrderBy().Filter();
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
            });
}

IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
            builder.EntitySet<Ebp>("Ebp");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

When I call the `GET` endpoint using `{{baseUrl}}/odata/coaching/ebp/all`, the result is in `camelCase` as I expect.

[image]

However, the second I introduce any `$select` or `$filter` options to query, my response changes to `PascalCase`

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in [this post](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1515#issuecomment-402032649). In the `AddNewtonSoftJson` method that is attached to the service collection, I should have set the `SerializerSettings.ContractResolver` to `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

```
services.AddOData();
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            IEnumerable<ODataOutputFormatter> outputFormatters =
                options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>()
                    .Where(foramtter => foramtter.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0);

            foreach (var outputFormatter in outputFormatters)
            {
                outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/odata"));
            }

        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.UseCamelCasing(false);
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for ours, this solve my problem when I use the "$expand" query option

Comment: Adding this worked for me:
.AddNewtonsoftJson(o=>o.UseCamelCasing(true));